# Alternate forms of $ \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \text P(n)=\sum\limits_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p(p-1)} $ with the prime zeta function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, closed-form, zeta-functions, constants

We know that: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\zeta(n)-1)=1$$ but what about with the [**Prime Zeta function $\text P(s)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PrimeZeta)?:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \text P(n)=0.77315666904979…$$

Now interchange the sum with the [prime numbers $ p_k$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prime&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22prime%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Function%22%7D)

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{p_m^n}= \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{p_m^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{p_n(p_n-1)}$$

which [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%28%28prime%28n%29-1%29prime%28n%29%29+from+1+to+999) the same decimal. There are also many [**prime-related constants**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/Prime-RelatedConstants.html). Another form [given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074358/please-help-me-evaluate-the-following-infinite-sum-sum-limits-k-1-infty?rq=1) by @reuns is with the [Euler Phi](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulerphi) and [Mobius](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=mobiusmu) functions :

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \text P(n)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)\ln(\zeta(n))}n-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)\ln(\zeta(n))}n= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)\ln(\zeta(n))}n-\text C= \gamma-\text B_1+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)\ln(\zeta(n))}n $$

where $\text P(s)=-\ln(\epsilon)+\text C+O(\epsilon),\epsilon>0$ as seen in [Formulas 3 throught 5 here on MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) and $\text C=\text B_1-\gamma$ with the [**Merten’s constant $\text B_1$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html) and [Euler Mascheroni constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=euler+mascheroni+constant). It also [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulergamma-mertens+constant%2B+sum%5Beulerphi%28n%29%2Fn+ln%28zeta%28n%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C999%7D%5D) the same decimal. The Euler phi sum is similar to [@Steven Clark’s formula ($14$) here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276255/questions-about-the-dirichlet-series-ks-sum-limits-pk-p-k-s).

If one read further in the [Merten’s constant article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html), then the [**amount of prime factors average deviation constant $\text B_2$**](http://oeis.org/A083342) appears giving:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \text P(n)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p(p-1)}=\text B_2-\text B_1= 0.77315666904979… $$

Now that a “closed form” has been found, are there any alternate forms of the $0.77315666904979…\,$ constant in terms of special functions, integrals, manipulated sums et cetera?

Comment: Some informations here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074358/please-help-me-evaluate-the-following-infinite-sum-sum-limits-k-1-infty?rq=1

Comment: To all: Euler phi is the [Euler totient function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=euler+totient)

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi (n)}{n}\,  \log (\zeta (n))=B_2-\gamma$ may not be what you're looking for, but perhaps it provides some insight. (see formula 13 at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html )

Comment: @StevenClark Actually, this formula answers the question. However, this $B_2$ constant is just named after the sum. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking formula (15) at the same link might provide some additional insight with respect to $B_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer contains more information based on chapter 22 of "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Hardy and Wright which hopefully provides a bit more insight.

Let

$$C(x)=\sum\limits_{p\le x} \frac{\log(p)}{p}\tag{1}$$

where $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and

$$\tau(x)=C(x)-\log(x)=O(1)\tag{2}$$

then

$$\sum\limits_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p}=\frac{C(x)}{\log (x)}+\int\limits_2^x\frac{C(t)}{t \log^2(t)}\,dt=1+\frac{\tau (x)}{\log (x)}+\int_2^x \frac{1}{t \log(t)}\,dt+\int_2^x \frac{\tau (t)}{t \log ^2(t)} \, dt$$ $$=\log(\log(x))+B_1+E(x)\tag{3}$$

where

$$B_1=1-\log(\log(2))+\int_2^\infty \frac{\tau(t)}{t \log^2(t)}\,dt\tag{4}$$

and

$$E(x)=\frac{\tau(x)}{\log(x)}-\int\limits_x^\infty \frac{\tau(t)}{t \log^2(t)}\,dt=O\left(\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)\tag{5}$$

so

$$\sum\limits_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p}=\log(\log(x))+B_1+o(1)\tag{6}$$

Also

$$B_1=\gamma+\sum\limits_p \left(\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+\frac{1}{p}\right)\tag{7}$$

so

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty P(n)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \log(\zeta(n))+\gamma-B_1\tag{8}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \log(\zeta(n))-\sum\limits_p \left(\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

A couple of other relationships are

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \nu(n)=x \log(\log(x))+B_1 x+o(x)\tag{9}$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Omega(n)=x \log(\log(x))+B_2 x+o(x)\tag{10}$$

where $\nu(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$ are the number of distinct and non-distinct primes dividing $n$.

Comment: (+1) Also see [Prime Nu](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeNu.html) and [Prime Omega](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeOmega.html). You have given many useful identities. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a formally relative simple answer. Wolfram Alpha is very fluent in numbers. Simply enter the number of your interest in the search/input field of Wolfram Alpha and have a look at the result.

The answer offers for example a continued fraction series for the truncated number. But Mathematica can do infinity numbers.

So continued fraction approximation for $n=20$:

$0.77315666904979512786 \approx  [0; 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 15, 12, 1, 19, 1, 9, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]$

Wolfram Alpha suggests some closed forms that are more or less good guesses. This is number representation theory.

Have a look at [0.77315666904979512786](https://oeis.org/search?q=0.77315666904979512786&sort=&language=&go=Search).  The non-search result is [A136141](https://oeis.org/A136141). I hope that helps.

For the given function $C(x)$ I am able to give many other representations.

$C(x)=\sum_{p=1}^{p\leq x}\frac{log(p)}{p}$.

$\text{StieltjesGamma}[1]-\text{StieltjesGamma}[1,1+(p\leq x)]$

The minuent is the generalized [StieltjesGamma](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StieltjesGamma.html) function.

In traditional form:

$\gamma _ 1-\gamma _ 1((p\leq x)+1)$.

And with that a whole bunch of different but not so new representations are available.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the closed form finder suggestion and the Oeis link. The small terms in the $[a_1,a_2,…]$ continued fraction are a good observation too. However, the question asked for an alternate form, not an approximation which usually happens with the “possible closed forms” in W.A.